# Regarding 1 tick in windows and posix

Tags: c++, windows, timespan

I am seeing code in C++ under windows.

It is mentioned that 1 tick is equal to 100 nanoseconds. Is this specific to windows? or Is this any generic standard, if it is what is name of the standard? Is this same on other OS also?

Reason for asking for above question I have to write platform independent code, if it is windows specific I have to add #ifdef WIN32 for this part of code.

Comment: 'Tick' is a very frequently used name for some small amount of time. I've seen it be 1/60th of a second as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is microsoft specific: [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks.aspx)

> The smallest unit of time is the tick, which is equal to 100
>   nanoseconds. A tick can be negative or positive.

In Linux systems you can use high granularity timers to get to 100 nanosecond accuracy but you definitely need to handle them separately.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a tick isn't specific to Microsoft, but its use in computer science is almost entirely limited to Windows. Most other systems (i.e. UNIX-like and POSIX-compliant systems) refer to sub-second timespans in millisecond, microsecond, nanosecond, etc. units. For example, the `struct timeval` type is defined (on my system) as:

```
struct timeval {
    __darwin_time_t         tv_sec;    /* seconds */
    __darwin_suseconds_t    tv_usec;   /* and microseconds */
};
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please comment so I know *why* you downvoted. It's not clear what problem you have with this answer.